# Issue with ‘VsTest’ task in azure devops CI build

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube

I am using sonarqube version 6.1 and i have sonarqube scanning task integrated with my azure CI build . I want to calculate code coverages too , so I have added `VsTest` task in my CI build (as mentioned in sonarqube-vsts integration documentation).
I am getting error in `VsTest` task when a build is queued . (All other sonarqube task is running fine)

The error is as below :

```
Error: The process ‘C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe’ failed with exit code 1
VsTest task failed.
```

Please let me know how can this be fixed . Build server I am using has VS2017 on it.

Here's the log :

```
Total tests: 14. Passed: 8. Failed: 6. Skipped: 0.
Test Run Failed.
Test execution time: 41.8253 Seconds
Results File: D:\VSTS Agent Folder\SO\41\s\TestResults\SC-DEOPSCI_MEA-DEVOPS1_2019-09-09_11_14_11.trx
##[warning]Vstest failed with error. Check logs for failures. There might be failed tests.
##[error]Error: The process 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe' failed with exit code 1
##[error]VsTest task failed.
Publishing test results to test run '1000042'
Test results remaining: 14. Test run id: 1000042
##[section]Async Command Start: Publish test results
Published Test Run : https://xyz.visualstudio.com/TipB/_TestManagement/Runs?runId=1000042&_a=runCharts
##[section]Async Command End: Publish test results
##[section]Finishing: VsTest - testAssemblies
```

Comment: The error you posted is insufficient for troubleshooting. Could you post the detailed vstest error log?

Answer (score 0):

The error shows that 6 tests failed. It is the expected behavior of Vstest task. When the tests failed, the task will fail too.

This may indicate that there is something going unexpectedly in your code. You should go back to your source code and fix the failed test cases. After they are fixed, you can rerun your pipeline.

If you didnot want failed tests to effect the next task after Vstest, You can change the **Control option** of the **next task**  to run the this task even if the previous task has failed.
[image]

Comment: thanks for the info. So, all test should pass is mandatory for this task to succeed?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Actually even if the task fails, you can still run the next tasks and publish your artifacts.